# Linked list Behaviour

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

Can Someone please explain the difference in Behaviour ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

// only for the 1st Node
void initNode(Node *head,int n){
    head->data = n;
    head->next =NULL;
}

void insertFront(Node *head, int n) {
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = n;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

void display(Node *head) {
    Node *list = head;
    while(list) {
        cout << list->data << " ";
        list = list->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
}


int main() 
{

    Node *l1 = new Node;

    initNode(l1,10);
    display(l1);
    insertFront(l1,5);
    display(l1);
    insertFront(l1,6);
    display(l1);
    insertFront(l1,7);
    display(l1);

    return 0;
}
```

Some how the nodes are not linking. The output is :
10

10

10

10

If The program is coded using pointer to a pointer as below then it works fine. what am is missing ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

// only for the 1st Node
void initNode(Node *head,int n){
    head->data = n;
    head->next =NULL;
}

void insertFront(Node **head, int n) {
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = n;
    newNode->next = *head;
    *head = newNode;
}

void display(Node *head) {
    Node *list = head;
    while(list) {
        cout << list->data << " ";
        list = list->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
}


int main() 
{

    Node *l1 = new Node;

    initNode(l1,10);
    display(l1);
    insertFront(&l1,5);
    display(l1);
    insertFront(&l1,6);
    display(l1);
    insertFront(&l1,7);
    display(l1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output correct as expected :

10

5 10

6 5 10

7 6 5 10

Comment: Your debugger can explain that probably better.

Comment: You are not updating `head` in the `InsertFront`  function, you  need to pass it as a reference, using `Node*& head`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, in function

```
void insertFront(Node *head, int n) {
  Node *newNode = new Node;
  newNode->data = n;
  newNode->next = head;
  head = newNode;
}
```

`head` is a copy of the pointer `l1` used in the scope of `main()`. When `head` is modified, `l1` is left unchanged. This is the reason why a pointer to `l1` (`&l1`) is passed to the function in the second case `void insertFront(Node **head, int n)`. Then `*head` is `l1`, not just a copy of `l1`.

First case is an example of passing argument by value, and the second case is passing an argument by reference [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

For instance, the following function is basically useless  :

```
void useless(int a){
  a=42;
}
```

If `int b=2;useless(b);cout<<b<<endl;` is called it will print `2`, not `42`.

The following function is the right way to go :

```
void rightwaytogo(int*a){
  *a=42;
}
```

Don't forget to write a function to `delete` the nodes of your linked list.

Comment: He should also prefer to use a reference to the head variable, as in `Node*& head`.